# linux kernel mnt_has_parent in pivot_root

Tags: linux-kernel

when implementing a namespace isolation solution i'm hitting this check in pivot_root

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6/source/fs/namespace.c#L3036

```
    if (!mnt_has_parent(root_mnt))
        goto out4; /* not attached */
```

and i'm super confused why this is in there.

as far as i understand this is the current root from the perspective of the calling process, which in initrd is initrd, or in my case is the host rootfs

```
 cat /proc/self/mountinfo 
27 27 0:2 / / rw - rootfs rootfs rw,size=469616k,nr_inodes=117404
```

why would that root mount have a parent at all? I cant imagine any normal hostos where that would be the case.

you can of course work around that by doing

```
mkdir /wtf
mount --rbind / wtf
chroot /wtf
```

now the current root has a parent. but... why?